# VECM Cointegration Relationship Coefficient(s) Interpretation

Tags: time-series, interpretation, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

Theory dictates that when there is one cointegration relationship, it's coefficient in a VECM must be statistically significant and negative to maintain the long-run equilibrium.

Nonetheless, when there are two cointegrating relationships (Coint 1 and 2), should both their coefficients, C(1) and C(2), be negative and statistically significant or only the first coefficient, C(1)? Thanks

a, b, c, d, e, and f are real numbers.

```
             Coint 1        Coint 2 
Var 1           1.00           0.00
Var 2           0.00           1.00
Var 3           a              d
Var 4           b              e
Constant        c              f
```

VECM:

```
              ∆Var1(t)
 Coint 1       C(1)
 Coint 2       C(2)
 ∆Var1(t-1)    C(3)
              ... etc
```

Comment: See [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=error+correction+negative+positive+user%3A53690) answers of mine to similar questions.